# Arduino: Upload Timeout error

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm new to the Arduino programming.
I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560 R3 and use Arduino IDE 1.5.5-r2.
I have a very simple program and when I try to upload, it locks near the end.
Some time appears to me the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

I am using the correct COM port and I have the right board selected

When I try to connect the Rx pin with the pin Tx, writing in the console I get the data correctly in the monitor.

Any ideias?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the tx and rx pins while uploading your sketch then plugging them in when you are done?

Comment: yes, I connect tx and rx pins just to make testing the serial port. But when I upload they are disconnected.

Comment: How can change Baudrate in Arduino Ide?

Comment: I use the same Baudrate but the error continues...

Comment: Have you tried a different cable? I had getsync issues left and right with my arduino fio. As soon as I changed the FTDI cable out it worked perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like auto-reset is not working. keep pressed reset and then click upload on the IDE, when the IDE say sketch size... release reset button. Many tries are needed to get the right timing. This happen because you are flooding the serial, try putting a delay right after `setup()`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. With the same Arduino board and IDEs 1.6.8 or 1.6.11 on Kubuntu Linux. While trying the "blink" example sketch, I got exactly the same error. My solution was the USB cable. When I tried another USB cable, it worked. Then I tried an older, supposedly broken, Arduino Mega 2560 R3 board, one that had shown some different errors. It also worked with the new cable.